# Returning All values Found from Recursive Function PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I have a situation where I need to build a breadcrumb string given the last category id, so i need to get all the parent cats. So I wrote a recursive function to do this but its only returning the top parent object.

So basically if my breadcrumb looks like this

```
All Categories -> Category 1 -> Subcategory 1 -> Subcategory 2
```

I am given the ID for Subcategory 2, in which case I need to return Subcategory 1, and Category 1.

```
    private function get_parent_category( $category_id )
    {
        $category = new ObjCategories();
        $category->get_object( "id=" . $category_id );
        if( !empty( $category->name ) ):
            $parent_category = new ObjCategories();
            $parent_category->get_object( "id=" . $category->parent );
            if( $parent_category->parent == 0 ):
                return $parent_category;
            else:

                $found[] = $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category->id );
                return $found;
            endif;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    }
```

I'm a noob when it comes to recursion so if the answer is obvious, then i apologize. Thanks in advance

PS- In this example I cannot use echo, I need to capture the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there are two good ways to solve situations like this.

**Option 1**

Adjust the return values to arrays only, and add every recursive step to the beginning or end of the array. Your code would look like this (with the unrelated stuff redacted):

```
private function get_parent_category( $category_id ) {
<shortened>
  if( $parent_category->parent == 0 ):
     return [$parent_category];
  else:
     $found = $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category->id );
     array_unshift( $found , $parent_category ); //or array_push
     return $found;
  endif;
<shortened>
```

**Option 2**

Or you can pass the end result by reference and fill it on the way down. This would look like this; you don't need explicit returns:

```
private function get_parent_category( $category_id , &$found) {
<shortened>
  if( $parent_category->parent == 0 ):
     $found[] = $parent_category;
  else:
     $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category->id , $found );
     $found[] = $parent_category;
  endif;
<shortened>
```

Some people have a strong opinion on which way is better, but in my opinion you can pick the one you like.

Comment: why do you have the brackets surrounding [$parent_category] in option 1?, Option 2 i can't use because it's depricated to pass by reference

Comment: the square brackets create an array that contains $parent_category as the only element. It's the same as array($parent_category). Call time pass by reference is depreciated or removed (depending on the version of PHP). But this would be for example `intval(&$i);`. Using references when defining a method is supported in all versions afaik.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your code has is the handling of the result merging, as well as small logical error, which are all in that part of your code:

```
if( $parent_category->parent == 0 ):
    return $parent_category;
else:
    $found[] = $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category->id );
    return $found;
endif;
```

What's wrong is, that your `$found` variable is an array, while your `$parent_category` variable is a single object. **Your function therefore returns different types.**

In the line `$found[] = $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category->id );` you recursively call your function and **inherently use the returned value as a single object**, that you add to your `$found` array, while the function returns all the found objects of the inner calls in an array, or the single root.

To solve that behavior, you should first of all make sure, that your function returns always the same type, by returning the root node as an array as well, that only contains the root in it:

```
return [$parent_category]; //The same as array($parent_category);
```

Then, in case the current node is not the root node, you would have to add the current node into your array and return the array:

```
$found = $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category->id );
array_unshift($found, $parent_category);
return $found;
```

The small logical error is, that you either return the `$parent_category` or call the recursive function with the `$parent_category->id`. You therefore forget about the current `$category`, that is never part of the list you return.

To fix that you need return the current category instead of the parent category, when returning the single object, as well as merging the current category into the result set instead of merging the parent into it. This can be done before the parent category is even calculated.

```
if( $category->parent == 0 ):
    return [$category];
else:
    $parent_category = new ObjCategories();
    $parent_category->get_object( "id=" . $category->parent );
    $found = $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category->id );
    array_unshift($found, $category);
    return $found;
endif;
```

**Your function will then work.**

Anyhow it is not very readable and it calls the `ObjCategories->get_object` method a lot. You can reduce these calls by separating the recursive part of your code from the one that needs to be called initially:

```
private function get_parent_category( $category_id )
{
    $category = new ObjCategories();
    $category->get_object( "id=" . $category_id );
    if( !empty( $category->name ) ):
        return $this->get_parent_category_recursive($category);
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}

private function get_parent_category_recursive($category) {
    if( $category->parent == 0 ):
        return [$category];
    endif;

    $parent_category = new ObjCategories();
    $parent_category->get_object( "id=" . $category->parent );

    $found = $this->get_parent_category( $parent_category );
    array_unshift($found, $category);
    return $found;
}
```

Like this the category with which the function is called is not calculated again, but is kept for a reuse instead.